# Excel conditional formatting doesn't work for cells with formulas

Tags: excel

I have the cells,  which include the formula-based value you see below:

[image]

I've applied the following formula:

```
  =$G$48:$G$64 = "Major programmes"
```

with the orange color, but unfortunately it seem to not work.

I found some answer here:

https://superuser.com/questions/352364/conditionally-format-a-cell-if-it-contains-formula

but it didn't work for me either.

Is there any chance  of conditional formatting the cells, which value is based on the formula?

Comment: It would be `=$G48 = "Major programmes"` and apply range `$G$48:$G$64`.

Comment: There is a comma at the end of the cells - that's why the condition is not true. Furthermore the formula for the condition should be `=$G48 = "Major programmes"`

Comment: If you need 'contains', you could use `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Major programmes",G48))`. If you need 'begins with', you could use `=SEARCH("Major programmes",G48)=1`.

Comment: Your cell's result has a training comma, your CF rule does not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a comer in cell g48 and not in your formula. if you  change it to   =$G$48:$G$64 = "Major programmes," it should work